# ¿Como deshabilito el modo de movimientos de eventos mensualesy mantener la interaccion en semanal?

Tags: fullcalendar

alguien que alguna vez halla trabajado con FUllCalendar, y halla podido deshabilitar los eventos movibles solo para cuando este en modo mensual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que verificar que no estes en la vista mensual para cuando el calendario reciba el evento drop, reviertes la operación, esto es lo que debes poner en los datos pasados a la función fullCalendar que tienes que añadir

```
eventDrop: function(ev,delta,revertFunc){
    //Aquí verifico que no esté seleccionado el botón "Month"
    if(!$('.fc-month-button').hasClass('fc-state-active')){
        //revierto la operación, esta función no hay que declararla es el 3er parámetro pasado al evento drop
        revertFunc(event);
    }
}
```

Aquí te dejo el código completo de mi fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2016-01-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2016-01-07',
            end: '2016-01-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2016-01-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2016-01-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2016-01-11',
            end: '2016-01-13'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2016-01-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-01-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2016-01-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2016-01-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2016-01-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2016-01-28'
        }
    ],
    eventDrop: function(ev,delta,revertFunc){
      if(!$('.fc-month-button').hasClass('fc-state-active')){
        revertFunc(event);
      }
    }
});
```